# Zotonic: How to create HTML pages containing Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, zotonic

I am exploring Zotonic and I am trying to create a page containing both HTML and Javascript (within  ). Yet, when I save my page, the Javascript is removed and not saved.

Is there any way to create a simple HTML page with Javascript?

Comment: Could you post your template code where you have included the javascript?

Comment: I was hoping I could use the editor to create an HTML page and add <script>...</script>. I am not even using templates, would this be the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add javascript directly into your templates, or you can add it in yoursite/lib/js/yourscript.js

If you add it in your sites lib directory, you can add it to your template like this:

```
{% lib "js/yourscript.js" %}
```

http://zotonic.com/docs/0.9/ref/tags/tag_lib.html?highlight=lib

It is not possible to add javascript from the content management system.